# Still produce result from multiple inner joins if one join fails

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following query which makes 2 inner joins. This works fine unless there are no entries for the account_id in the ratings table.

```
SELECT c.comment_id, a.account_id, a.first_name, a.second_name, a.points, a.image_url, c.body, c.creation_time, AVG(r.rating_overall)
FROM comments AS c
INNER JOIN accounts AS a
ON c.account_id=a.account_id
INNER JOIN ratings AS r
ON r.baker_id=a.account_id
WHERE c.blog_id = ?
GROUP BY c.comment_id, a.account_id, a.first_name, a.second_name, a.points, a.image_url, c.body, c.creation_time
ORDER BY c.creation_time DESC
```

How do I make this query return a result even if there are no entries in the ratings table. In other words produce `AVG(r.rating_overall) = 0` whenever there are no ratings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM comments AS c
  INNER JOIN accounts AS a
  ON c.account_id=a.account_id
  LEFT JOIN ratings AS r
  ON r.baker_id=a.account_id
```

....

that will return all rows from the previous join, and only the rows that matches the last join. If there's no match, all columns from rating tables will be null.

You learn more about joins on this [visual explanation of SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Wow thanks! I will have to learn what left join is now :) o.O

Comment: @AmyNeville you're welcome :) i added a link with a nice explanation about joins, hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give you a tick in a sec when it lets me - thanks I'll check out that visual explanation maybe it will help me remember better :)